# React - AWS Amplify Auth Federated Sign In Facebook

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I develop react sign in page using amplify with cognito user pool.
I have setup Federated identity provider sign-in using Facebook and use Facebook graph API version v17.0
I have deploy page to s3 and using cloudfront.
The problem is when open on pc browser it work perfectly with facebook sign in and there is other app that us flutter develop mobile app using webview_flutter open this website and tab on facebook button it work on iOS that use WKWebView but on Android WebView it show this.

[image: Log in Disabled]

I don't know that amplify using Facebook SDK for Javascript or for Android when open on Android device that show Log in Disabled error or from webview_flutter that use Android WebView.

Thank you for your help